# Disappearing icons

Tags: qt

My icons will hide after run app which i place on form design.

Im use QT 4.8.4 configure with such keys -release -static -opensource -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg

[At design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByodY.png)

[After run app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgufa.png)

Why this is happ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make a resource (QRC) file? If not, the icons will show up in the creator, but not in the final compiled executable. The relative path to your icons are differ when running your applications because then the starting point of relative paths are the directory containing the exe.
Try to use Qt resource system: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/resources.html

```
OP: And 1 more thing, when i compile project with shared QT lib then icons are ok on this places in runtime
```

[EDITED]
 You must link the imageformat plugins statically to your application too (they cannot be loaded dynamically during runtime as with the shared lib version). See developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/… for the details, please. The actual set of imageformat plugins to link depends on your icons and other graphics you use. qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/13367

Comment: Yes. Project contain qrc file with icons and in desiger action & button ico set from this res file.

Comment: And 1 more thing, when i compile project with shared QT lib then icons are ok on this places in runtime.

Comment: I have found something that may help you: 

You must link the imageformat plugins statically to your application too (they cannot be loaded dynamically during runtime as with the shared lib version).

See http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins for the details, please. The actual set of imageformat plugins to link depends on your icons and other graphics you use.
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/13367

Comment: So it looks like im use 
`Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN( qjpeg );`
but i should use:
`Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qico);`